# Работа с GridBagLayout()

Tags: java, swing

Подскажите пожалуйста. Имеется панель:

```
JPanel jPanel2=new JPanel();
jPanel2.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
```

На нее добавляется метка определенных размеров:

```
private JLabel imageLabel=new JLabel();
imageLabel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,400));
jPanel2.add(imageLabel,new GridBagConstraints(0,0,17,1,1,1,GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST,GridBagConstraints.NONE,new Insets(1,1,1,1),0,0));
```

Если я правильно понимаю, то моя метка занимает с левой верхней позиции 17 строк и 1 столбец, но при попытке добавить справа от него 17 элементов получается ерунда:

```
JButton jButtonFileImage=new JButton("Выбрать фото");
        jPanel2.add(jButtonFileImage,new GridBagConstraints(1,0,1,1,1,1,GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST,GridBagConstraints.NONE,new Insets(1,1,1,1),0,0));
jPanel2.add(new JLabel("Буба"),new GridBagConstraints(GridBagConstraints.RELATIVE,0,1,1,1,1,GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST,GridBagConstraints.NORTH,new Insets(1,1,1,1),0,0));
```

Подскажите как справа от фото добавить 17 JButton или JLabel?

Answer (score 2):

Ошибка была в

```
jPanel2.add(imageLabel,new GridBagConstraints(0,0,17,1,1,1,GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST,GridBagConstraints.NONE,new Insets(1,1,1,1),0,0));
```

Я задал 1 строку 17 столбцов, надо:

```
GridBagConstraints(0,0,1,17,1,1,GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST,GridBagConstraints.NONE,new Insets(1,1,1,1),0,0));
```